# Kendo UI MVC - Grid Correct way of using a ComboBox in a popup-mode data grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datagrid, kendo-ui

I have a grid that shows quotes, I'd like to use a ComboBox to show a list of available clients and users that can be assigned to the quote (From the database).

Can anyone advise on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this example will be useful? - http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html

That uses a DropDownList in edit mode, rather than a ComboBox, but the two controls are very similar.